# Why does NET MAUI handle screen rotations itself?

Tags: c#, android, maui, maui-android

I created a NET MAU app from the official template and inside Platforms - Android - MainActivity.cs found this code:

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
}
```

That means, .NET MAUI handles `ConfigChanges.Orientation` by itself. Why is that? Also I figured out that rotation still works, it's not blocked. But what does NET MAUI behind the scenes / what's the reason NET MAUI handles that manually?

Answer (score 0):

> Also I figured out that rotation still works, it's not blocked.

If you want the screen to stay in `Portrait` or `Landscape`, you can set the `ScreenOrientation` as follows:

```
ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait
```

Or

```
ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape
```

Usage example:

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true,ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)] 
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
}
```